# Hortonworks Hadoop cluster on Docker in Windows

Tags: hadoop, docker-compose, windows-10, hortonworks-data-platform

Hi I am trying to set up a Hortonworks hadoop cluster on Docker in Windows 10 pro following the steps in the below mentioned link.
https://medium.com/@sahputra/hortonworks-cluster-on-docker-5084ab599d6c

I am facing an error while pulling the ambari server image. The error says that there is a login issue and I am unable to overcome that.

Did anyone try this way or any other way? It would be helpful if I could get the guidance from this community.

PS: I am a novice in Linux and Docker

Comment: So given that you say you're a novice, I would suggest not doing this and just download the pre-existing HDP Sandbox. It'll basically require the same amount of resources as Docker, so you're not gaining anything by using Docker here

Comment: Plus, he didnt even show how he configured Hadoop after Ambari was up... There's no volume mounts, so all the data is ephemeral (will not survive a restart).

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 thank you for the response. The intent in using the docker is to set up a Spark ML cluster on top of the Hadoop cluster to make the environment production friendly.

Comment: Okay, so you say that, and I just see a bunch of buzzwords... You do not need Hadoop or Docker (or Linux) to run Spark ML on windows. Spark doesn't run in Docker all well at all outside of Kubernetes (networking and serialization is figured out by the framework)... Starting a Spark or YARN cluster would be much simpler without Docker and you would then not be running JVM containers within Docker containers within a Windows hypervisor (i.e: you're making it too complex)

Comment: I understand. But the requirement was as such that the data is need to be dealt in Hadoop and further be analysed using ML in Spark layer. And all this is to be done in docker.

Comment: I'm not sure who is putting that requirement on you... The blog you found makes their own containers, by the way, and isn't even using a Hadoop or Spark container... If you truly want to use a production environment setup, I suggest looking into Hortonworks Cloudbreak product

Comment: Oh yes, I had skimmed through its documentation. It was closely matching with what is needed. I thought if anyone would help me on setting up hadoop cluster in docker I can set it up and further suggest that there are easy and better alternatives.

Comment: Personally, I've had limited success with these images, but YMMV https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench/blob/master/README.md